# Reversing epoch time conversion

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Im using moment.js to convert a long/epoch time in to a humane readable format:

```
function convertValue(x) {

    var mytime = x; // x = 1460554200000000

    mytime = moment.utc(mytime).utcOffset(moment().format('ZZ'));
    mytime = mytime.format('DD-MM-YY HH:mm:ss.SSS');
    mytime = mytime + ' (' + moment().format('[UTC]ZZ') + ')';

    return myTime;

}
```

Which `myTime` would return something like: 14-05-16 15:55:05.000 (UTC+100)

How can i do the opposite, so, if i was to receive something like: 29-01-16 14:35:05.000 (UTC+100) and convert back to an epoch time?

Comment: You can use [`moment(string, formatstring)`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) to parse a string with a given format back into a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a given `moment` object, if you want the result as a *string*:

- Use `.format('x')` for the timestamp in milliseconds
- Use `.format('X')` for the timestamp in seconds

However, if you want the result as a *number*:

- Use `.valueOf()` for the timestamp in milliseconds
- Use `.unix()` for the timestamp in seconds

However, with regards to the code you provided:

- The offset `UTC+100` is nonstandard and somewhat ambiguous.  It could be `UTC+10`, `UTC+10:00`, `UTC+0100`, or `UTC+01:00`.
- `DD-MM-YY` may be confusing to users, as it using two digit years, and is in reverse order of what is usually expected.  Use `YYYY-MM-DD` if you're intending it to be used by a large number of people, or if you're going for something locale specific then make sure you're using separators that are common in the locale.  Usually `/` or `.`
- You're pairing the timestamp given with the *current* offset, rather than the offset in effect at the given time.  That's going to fail in many locations where the time zone offset changes for daylight saving time and other time zone changes.
- Your code should just be:

  ```
  var mytime = moment(x).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss.SSS [UTC]ZZ');
  ```
- To create a moment object from a string in a particular format, simply provide that format when parsing. So, the reverse function would be:

  ```
  var x = moment(mytime, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss.SSS [UTC]ZZ').valueOf();
  ```

Answer (score 1):

As long as you can coerce it back in to a moment object, you should be able to use `moment().format('x')` to get back to a Unix timestamp.

If you're talking about parsing a non standard date string in to a moment object, that's a lot more difficult. Since you know the format it was output as you should be able to use `moment(dateString, formatString)` to create a moment out of it.